# Some problems displaying data in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, localization, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I use ui-grid in my tutorial project.

Here is the defenition inside controller:

```
(function () {
      "use strict"; 
angular.module("workPlan").controller("workPlanListController",["$http","$log",workPlanListController]);

function workPlanListController($http,$log) {
    var self = this;

    this.gridOptions = {
        expandableRowTemplate: 'expandableRowTemplate.html',
        //expandableRowHeight: 150,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged(null, function (row) {
                if (row.isExpanded) {
                    row.entity.subGridOptions = {
                        columnDefs: [{ name: 'name' },
                                     { name: 'gender' },
                                     { name: 'company' }]
                    };

                    $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
                      .success(function (data) {
                          row.entity.subGridOptions.data = data;
                      });
                }
            });
        }
    }
  this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      { name: 'PId', field: 'id'},
      { name: 'PName',field: 'name'},
      { name: 'PAge', field: 'age'}];



    $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
      .success(function (data) {
          self.gridOptions.data = data;
      });
}
})();
```

Here is the view I get:

[image]

But there is problem, as you can see on the image above, the content of field **id** appears under the **PAge** column and the content of field **PAge** appears under the **PId** column.

Any idea why this happens? Why does the content of one column appear under another column? Could it be related to localization (in my project I am using Hebrew)?

Comment: Hey, couldn't reproduce your issue. Could you look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TAbvGUsDKS6pcbEkGWV6?p=preview) and tell me if you still have it ?

Comment: Are you using the same version og Angular and ngGrid as in @Goodzilla's Plunker?

Comment: I need to set it in my tutorial project and to check

Comment: @Andreas, I use angularjs 1.3.8 version and ui-grid v3.0.6

Comment: Assuming the page is set to render text RTL, I was able to reproduce the issue [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuWYOjnIq6iArlyZq5vY?p=preview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the issue may be related to localization/language. Assuming the page is set up to render text right-to-left, the issue can be reproduced on [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuWYOjnIq6iArlyZq5vY?p=preview).

Unfortunately, it looks like [ui-grid does not yet support RTL text](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/692), but there are workarounds available.

Applying the following CSS to your grid will align your columns and headers appropriately:

```
.grid[dir=rtl] .ui-grid-header-cell,
.grid[dir=rtl] .ui-grid-cell{
  float:right !important;
} 

.grid[dir=rtl] .ui-grid-scrollbar-vertical {
  width: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  right:inherit;
  left: 4px;
  top: 0;
}
```

[Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IBZnH2gEO4MRA6y2F1fL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
    (function () {
        "use strict";

    angular.module('app',['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.expandable',
    'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.pinning']).controller('MainCtrl',
    function($scope,$http,$log) {

        $scope.name = 'World';
        // Do things

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            expandableRowTemplate: 'expandableRowTemplate.html',
            //expandableRowHeight: 150,
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged(null, function (row) {
                    if (row.isExpanded) {
                        row.entity.subGridOptions = {
                            columnDefs: [{ name: 'name' },
                                         { name: 'gender' },
                                         { name: 'company' }]
                        };

                        $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
                          .success(function (data) {
                              row.entity.subGridOptions.data = data;
                          });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
          { name: 'PId', field: 'id'},
          { name: 'PName',field: 'name'},
          { name: 'PAge', field: 'age'}];

    $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
          .success(function (data) {
              $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
          });

    });


    }());

HTML:
======
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-expandable class="grid"></div>
    </div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

CSS:
====
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

expandableRowTemplate.html:
===========================

<div ui-grid="row.entity.subGridOptions" style="height:150px;"></div>

you refer this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/TAbvGUsDKS6pcbEkGWV6?p=preview
or replace the js file. it will work well.
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo:  { name: 'PId', field: 'id', }

Delete the comma and maybe it work.

Greets Christian